# Sharing tables/models across LINQ database model

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am not sure of the exact terminologies involved so please bear with me.

I have an ASP.NET MVC website - my first go at using this - and I decided to spread the Database Model (dbml file in other words) across 2 logical mappings. I thought they were logical until I decided to include my "Tags" table in both of the dbml files. This now makes the generate code duplicate a "Tags" class and therefore will not permit me to compile.

The obvious way round this is to get rid of my logical split across the 2 models and just whack all the tables and their relationships into a giant dbml file. This is what I will do if I cannot find a simple solution.

Does anyone have a solution to this probably common issue? Is it a simple case of inheriting one model from another making the various model/entities available everywhere?

Thanks in advance, mo

Comment: Can you simply give them different namespaces?

Comment: I would prefer not to put them into separate namespaces and it also avoids the problem somewhat because the code generator will still build classes and methods for the Tag table in 2 separate places. This means any custom methods I wish to implement in a partial Tag class must be duplicated.

Comment: Yeah, with the "don't want to duplicate custom methods" requirement, you're out of luck. Into a single DBML file you go.

Comment: Thanks guys I ended up doing that eventually! I think it's a personal taste kind of thing where I personally would like my LINQ models split according to task/behaviour e.g. a content.dbml and an events.dbml that have a common "Tags" class shared without having to resort to skullduggery.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, technically, you can create  them 2 different dbmls and remove duplicates from ones code, but you'll have to do it everytime you change your model.
would be kinda creepy.